# How to disable all CLI test logs in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4, command-line-interface

I've managed to disable the `ActiveRecord` related logs by setting `config.active_record.logger = nil` in `config/environments/test.rb`

I'm still getting the following outputs however:

```
Processing by Admin::WebsitesController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"226"}
  Rendered admin/websites/_form.html.erb (6.8ms)
  Rendered admin/websites/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (7.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 36ms (Views: 33.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

I've tried the following options but they didn't help:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = nil
config.action_controller.logger = nil
config.action_view.logger = nil
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try setting the application log level to `:fatal` or `4` (they are one and the same). E.g. in `config/environments/test.rb`:

```
config.log_level = :fatal
```

---

See [the Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#log-levels) for more info, like the available log levels:

> The available log levels are: `:debug`, `:info`, `:warn`, `:error`, `:fatal`, and `:unknown`, corresponding to the log level numbers from 0 up to 5 respectively.